# GFCI conversion trouble: receptacle not screwing into outlet support plate

Tags: receptacle, gfci, screws

I'm trying to convert old "razor only" receptacles to GFCI protected ones in bathrooms. Since the old outlets are large 2-gang 4" boxes, I had to get GFCI conversion kits ([manufacturer's specs](https://new.abb.com/products/7TBA126770R0007/4in-square-gfci-conversion-kit)) with a 2-gang, 1 centered receptacle support plate and wall plate:

[image: GFCI conversion kit]

**The problem**: the holes where the new GFCI receptacle should screw in (the small circles in the support plate at the right in the image above) are untapped.

It is extremely difficult to screw in the receptacle's screws into those holes.
The hole size seems about right, matching the shaft diameter of the screw without the threads. A 7/64" drill bit slides smoothly in the hole.

The receptacle's screws are tapered at the tips and they can get the threading started, but it gets stuck quickly. I tried using the old receptacle's screws to continue the threading and it is so difficult that the screw head broke. I also found another switch with what appear to be self-tapping screws of the same thickness and threading, and they can't even get started.

I unfortunately don't have taps. I also thought of drilling the holes a bit larger, but the next drill bit size seems to be 1/8" which looks too big.

Am I missing something? I would think this must be a standardized part that is meant for simple installation without so much difficulty or additional steps such as thread tapping. For example, [this how-to guide](https://www.electrical-online.com/how-to-replace-a-razor-only-receptacle-with-a-gfci/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Remember you can just fit a GFCI upstream of here

All GFCI devices have the ability to protect downline locations.  So if you know where this outlet location is *fed from*, then you can simply fit the GFCI device *there instead*, and leave the receptacle as you found it or use a plain receptacle.

I mention that because a lot of people don't think it's GFCI protected unless there's a GFCI receptacle *right here*.  That's not true.

### This is the only decent solution I have seen

... to the **GFCI/Decora into a 4" box** problem.  I'm sorry that ABB didn't tap it, and this does seem like a weird oversight for such a prestigious company, but this thing is such a win otherwise.

- The problem with other shallow plates is **they provide nowhere for the Decora cover plate screws to go**, which go just outboard of the receptacle mounting screws.  So you wind up with Decora cover plates missing, or floppy-doppy, and then they cut you or get broken.  No thanks.
- Domed 4" covers (which are their own cover-plate) force you to mutilate the GFCI - the ears that catch the cover screws are too tall to fit under the dome, so you must break them off. This means you will never be able to use the GFCI anywhere else.
- Deeper "mud rings" only work *if* you're lucky and the mud ring itself allows for those Decora screw positions. Some do not.

### So learn to tap

You need a #6-32 tap, and a tap holder to match, and these are just a few bucks.

When tapping, whenever you run into a spike of torque resistance, just "back off" 1/2 turn. That lets the chips clear out of the cut.

Taps come in gradual, normal and short (bottoming).   Don't use bottoming. Normal is fine.

If you're in school, see if the school has a "maker space". They probably have a set of taps.

Comment: I think this is the best and most complete answer. Ultimately tapping the holes is what is needed. Thank you for mentioning the required tap. Right now with some difficulty, I successfully managed to force the screws of the receptacle into the plate. 1. Lubricant helped tremendously (WD-40). 2. The screws did not go in perfectly perpendicularly which probably made it more difficult. Due to the difficulty with screwing, I first secured the receptacle onto the support plate and connected the wires later. A huge thank you to everyone for your comments!

Answer (score 3):

You may just need a better support plate, like [this one from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/4-in-Square-Single-Device-Mud-Ring-1-2-in-Raised-8772/202056191?MERCH=REC-_-pipsem-_-202058436-_-202056191-_-N):

[image]

"*Mounting holes are pre-tapped to accept devices faster*"

Comment: Maybe so. The one I got is the only conversion kit I've found (I'm not in the US). Is it typical to need to tap these plates? P.S. I added a link to the manufacturer's specs.

Comment: The conversion kit is really nothing special - just the stuff you need to mount a Decora style (that's the norm for GFCI dual receptacles) device in a 4" box. If you have a big box store (Home Depot/Lowe's), a decent traditional hardware store or an electrical supply house you should have no problem finding something like what I listed "pre-tapped".

Comment: The one I got is [the only one Lowe's carries](https://www.lowes.ca/product/wall-plates/iberville-2-gang-gfci-conversion-wall-plate-stainless-steel-264247) and [the one from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/leviton-2-gang-wall-plate-1-gfci-chrome/1000154177) looks identical (though there's no image of the support plate) even though it's branded Leviton instead. Aside from being absurdly priced, there is still no mention of "pre-tapped". I'll call and ask. Or I might try to find a tap if I can figure out the correct one. Quite an unexpected pain.

Comment: If you can't find one pre-tapped, they do make self-threading screws. They may be called "self-tapping", although that often refers to self-drilling screws (have a tiny drill bit on the tip) instead, which isn't what you want. They look like a normal machine screw, except the thread is tapered at the end. But it seems odd to me that these aren't already tapped, I have never encountered that before in the US.

Comment: @Nate OP is in Canada. I checked the Lowe's site he linked to find out where, and both there and the nearby Home Depot, the only brand is Iberville (i.e., same as what OP already got), everything ridiculously overpriced, etc. Which really surprised me as for basic stuff like this (no actual electrical stuff involved, just sheet metal) I would expect Canada to have the same selection as US with a moderate markup due to the exchange rate.

Comment: @Nate The screws on the GFCI receptacle are tapered, so maybe they are "self-tapping"? But it is incredibly difficult to go past 1-2 threads in once it gets to the less tapered part of the screw and I'm afraid of breaking it. Another switch I found lying around (Leviton) has tapered screws with four cuts into the sides at the taper (looks a bit like a tap), but I could not even get it to start threading.

Comment: Then they should tap. You can really crank on these screws quite a bit without damaging them, although you might have to worry about stripping the head out (I normally use hex-headed versions with a ratchet for assembling steel shelving and patio furniture and have never broken one)

Comment: @manassehkatz The branding is confusing because it says Iberville, Thomas & Betts (Memphis, TN), but the product info is from ABB, and at least on the wall plate it is printed "Made in Canada" on the back. Try to decipher that. The prices as you noticed are unbelievably overpriced (I found some small stores incredibly listing the same for $15+). Lowe's price is relatively "cheap" even if it's still a crazy markup. Btw, the store locations shown to you are probably based on your IP/routing.

Comment: @Nate For fear of breaking the new receptacle's screws, I just got the thread started (~2 turns in, mostly clearing the plate, but getting stuck due to exhausting the tapered portion of the screw), then used one of the old outlet's screws (flat end). The shaft of the screw actually sheared a bit below the head. Luckily it was easy to remove with vice grips, but I'm a bit concerned about trying that again.

Comment: I would have fully expected the plate to be supplied with self-tapping screws.  That's not that unusual.  It helps to know how to tap; after the tap starts to get stiff you should back off 1/2 turn then resume.

Comment: The thread cutting screws should be case hardened, while ordinary machine screws would generally not be. Lubrication might help preserve the threads of your cutting screw, but I've never needed it for sheet metal. Taps for electrical screws are generally fairly inexpensive, if you aren't comfortable using these screws. Still a bit mystified that these holes didn't come tapped for you, though. As Harper said, you might need to back off occasionally.

Comment: @adatum You're right that the store it showed me may not be "your" store. But it is a link to Lowes Canada - and I think that's the key. Lowes US (and Home Depot as I pictured above) has a **lot** more variety and much lower prices than Canada. I'm really a bit surprised.

Comment: @Harper The kit comes with two sets (different lengths) of two screws. They are not self-tapping, just flat ended, but they are just for securing the wall plate to the receptacle's (thankfully threaded) screw holes. I did back off maybe a quarter turn when threading got stiff, and even went back and forth a few times, but when it got really stuck, it no longer helped. I didn't try using lubricant though, which I will if I try again.

Comment: @adatum -- have you tried an electrical supply house? a single gang Decora cover for a 4" square box is a rather standard part AFAIK, or you can use a 4" square single gang mudring with a standard 1 gang Decora cover....

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel That overpriced conversion kit **is** just a 4" square single gang mudring + a 1 gang Decora cover.

Comment: @manassehkatz -- the cover's not quite the same, actually...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I don't know any electrical supply house. I just searched every hardware store I could think of, did online searches for "gfci conversion" or "2-gang 1 outlet", etc. I'm not sure what a mudring is, but what I got is exactly what I need, except that for some reason the holes are not tapped. I got 4 of these kits, and I even inspected the others in case the first one I opened accidentally didn't get tapped holes. Nope, they're all untapped.

Comment: @manassehkatz No, not t "just" that.  It's got holes in all the right places to address **the problem with Decora cover plate screws**.  Most solutions just ignore that, and expect you to mutilate your devices, or have floppy cover plates.   The "better support plate from Home Depot" pictured above is a fail, and will give floppy cover plates.  The domed 4" square covers require mutilating.  The ABB kit is the first thing I've seen that actually addresses the problem instead of ignoring it. A mud ring will also work if it's tall enough, but that's just dumb luck.

Comment: @Harper Well, it looks like what I've got in front of me (but I'm not taking apart the GFCI to see for sure...) is https://www.homedepot.com/p/RACO-4-in-Square-Exposed-Work-Cover-for-1-GFCI-Device-808C/202056256 which also solves the problem, but doesn't look as nice as the normal Decora cover.

Comment: That is the the domed one I mentioned.  Pop the cover off and look at the Decora receptacle inside, you'll see the installer was forced to cut off the ears that give the Decora covers a place to screw into.  That device can only be used in this type of cover, now, and is ruined for use anywhere else.  I am reluctant to do that to a $20 GFCI.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like, from the huge amount of discussion in the comments, that you have already expended enough energy on this to have been able to go to the store and buy the necessary tap. The tap you need will likely cost just a few US dollars.

The tap size needed for US style electrical fixture mounting screws is #6 - 32 NC.

You can even use the small tap by clamping its top square tang into a small pair of vice grip pliers in the case you want to avoid buying the special tapping tool holder. You use the tap very similar to the way you have been trying to use screws to make threads in the holes of the cover plate. Screw the tap in place about 3/4 to 1 turn and then reverse it back 1/4 turn before proceeding in the forward direction again.

Comment: Thanks! I agree that ultimately tapping is the correct way to go. Special thanks for mentioning the needed tap size.